# Change theme of android app on select

Tags: android

in main Action bar i have White theme and purple theme, if i select the purple theme  app color should change to purple color and if i select white app color should change to white color, respectively button and text color also should change.

I tried in my color.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#36286b</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#36286b</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#36286b</color>
    <color name="button_pressed">#000000</color>
    <color name="button_focused">#ff4081</color>
    <color name="button_default">#36286b</color>
    <color name="button_default1">#f2e9da</color>
    <color name="background_white">#f2e9da</color>
    <color name="background_purple">#36286b</color>
    <color name="textcolor_purple">#36286b</color>
    <color name="textcolor_white">#f2e9da</color>
    <drawable name="backgroundhome_white">@drawable/kar1</drawable>
    <drawable name="backgroundhome_purple">@drawable/kar</drawable>
</resources>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="Purple" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="white" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>


    </style>
```

If I select White App should changed to white, if i select Purple App should changed to purple

Comment: which buttons do you want to change?

Comment: Your two themes are the exact same...

Comment: try this link https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar

Comment: still i didn't get, anyone please give examples please

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your activity with an `Intent`

Theme must be set this way :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Purple);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
}
```